# Double each.do Loop iterating over same model

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, loops, each

I have a Model Lessons. Each lesson can be assigned to a Section (string between 1-10, :section) via a Dropdown field. The Section is a column of the Lessons table. A Lesson belongs to a model Courses (via :course_id)

I am trying to display this construction in a Sidebar, split up into section with the Lessons of each section below the Section and only the Lessons belonging to that specific course (via :course_id) See Screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of Sidebar, currently looping over the same database entries]

With the following code, I get the number of Sections that have been selected in a Lesson entry (Here 2, Section 1 and 2), but the code is looping over the same Lessons.

```
<div id="sidebar-nav">
  <ul id="dashboard-menu">
    <strong>Curriculum</strong><br><br>
    <% Lesson.where(course_id: @course).select(:section).each do |section| %>
    <div class="panel curriculum-navigation__section" ng-class="">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="lecture-3"><%= @lesson.section %>. Section</div>

      <ol>
        <% Lesson.where(course_id: @course).each do |lesson| %>
        <br>

        <li><%= link_to lesson.name, lesson %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ol><br>
    </div>
    <% end %>    
  </div>
```

Could anybody point me to a solution? Am I even solving this problem the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your data structure is backwards. If you have:

```
- Course
  - Section
    - Lesson
```

As a hierarchical structure then you should define and use it that way so your code would look lie:

```
class Course
  has_many :sections
  has_many :lessons,   through: :sections
end
class Section
  belongs_to: :course
  has_many    :lessons
end
class Lesson
  belongs_to  :section
end

<% @course.sections.each do |section| %>
  ...
    <% sections.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--- updated ---

If you have no Section model then I would consider doing the following:

```
class Course
  def sections
    lessions.map(&:section).uniq
  end
  def lessons_for_section(section)
    lessons.filter { |l| l.section == section }
  end
end

<% @course.sections.each do |section| %>
  ...
    <% @course.lessons_for_section(section).each do |lesson| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

(I have made the assumption that you are always going to work with all the lessons, if not the above would be more efficiently written as a scoped query)

Comment: So right now Section is not a Model. It is just a string column of the Lesson model. I tried to avoid creating a Section model just for this if possible...In the long term I will probably implement it this way but was wondering if there is a solution with just the lesson model

Comment: See my changes above